# Is there a better way to add the grpc extension when creating Laravel Homestead VM(Vagrant)?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, grpc, homestead

In my workplace, we have started using Homestead in order to streamline our Laravel development.

Setup:

- MacOs Catalina,
- Homestead v12.0.0
- Settler v11.0.0 (Ubuntu 20.04)

We are using php7.4 for our projects so on my Homestead.yaml file my sites setup looks like this:

```
sites:
- map: site1.test
  to: /home/vagrant/projects/site1/public
  php: "7.4"
- map: site2.test
  to: /home/vagrant/projects/site2/public
  php: "7.4"
```

A project of ours requires the grpc extension to be used. From the installation instructions (https://grpc.io/docs/languages/php/quickstart/) it seems that Pecl is used to install the grpc extension. So on my after.sh script I have added the following section:

```
sudo phpize
sudo pecl -d php_suffix="7.4" install grpc &&

sudo touch /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/grpc.ini &&
echo 'extension=grpc' | sudo tee /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/grpc.ini
sudo phpenmod -v 7.4 grpc
```

Which works fine, but it compiles the grpc extension every time a VM is created which takes some time. Are there any better solutions to make the process a bit faster?

Comment: For Ubuntu I found the easiest way to install PHP and extensions is to add [this repository](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) in the list of repos (instructions are in many places e.g. [here](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-on-ubuntu/)). You can probably add these steps in your after script. It's faster than compiling, but still not ideal. The ideal solution would be a custom docker image with these steps pre-ran, but I wouldn't know how to integrate that in your current setup

Comment: Thanks for your answer @apokryfos, I am trying to stay away from anything that needs major maintenance. Following an external repo combined with the changes that come to Homestead on a regular basis isn't ideal.
 I know the best idea would be to get my own containers running, but my team isn't used to this kind of workflow yet. Having vagrant ( it's a VM rather than a container) is something new, so one step at a time :) . Will have a quick check on the repo your proposed, check if the version of php-grpc is compatible though for the short term.